# AWS Lambda Python to Write Logs in definite log group and log stream

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to the AWS and Python world. I was toying with AWS Lambda and tried to create Python Lambda function that outputs the logs in a Log Group and Log Stream that are defined by me but with no success !
Ex: (Log Group = "Pink", Log Stream = "Panther")

The Code I am using is :

```
import watchtower

import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger('sample_logger')

LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

cw_handler = watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler(log_group='Pink', stream_name='Panther')


def lambda_handler(event,context):

LOGGER.addHandler(console_handler)

   LOGGER.addHandler(cw_handler)

   LOGGER.info("some message")
```

It does create the log group but not the stream and logs are sent to the default Lambda log group. Can somebody help figure out what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I do want to point out that some of the logs happen outside your function's code, like the started/stopped messages. So if you continue down this path your logs are going to be split between multiple log groups which may not be desirable.